# Passing different arguments in run command based on github event type?

Tags: github-actions, fastlane

I have a GH workflow that is triggered by several events:

```
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - publish-*
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 1 * * *'
  workflow_dispatch:
```

The main job runs a fastlane action to deploy the app to Testflight, but needs to change the test groups to distribute to based on what kind of event triggered the workflow. Currently I have this:

```
- name: Deploy to Testflight
  run: |
    if [[ "${{ github.event_name }}" == "push" ]]; then
      TEST_GROUPS="Beta testers"
    else  
      TEST_GROUPS="Reviewers"
    fi    
    bundle exec fastlane deploy_to_testflight groups:"$TEST_GROUPS"
```

Is there a better way of doing this, perhaps by setting the workflow or job env var based on the event?

Comment: `env: TEST_GROUPS: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' && 'Beta testers' || 'Reviewers' }}`